# Manipulating dataframe in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame like

```
   ID       DATE         TS_EVENT              X   Y  Z
ID0026A  2013-01-03 2013-01-03 8:31:09 PM     25   0  0
ID0026A  2013-01-03 2013-01-03 8:31:09 PM      0   0  0
ID0026A  2013-01-03 2013-01-03 11:22:55 PM     0   0  0
ID0026A  2013-01-03 2013-01-03 11:36:05 PM     0   0  0
ID0026A  2013-01-03 2013-01-03 11:36:05 PM     0   0  0
ID0026A  2013-03-27 2013-01-03 11:36:05 PM   100 354 25
```

Now I want to return a dataframe which will have the four columns ID,DATE,X,Y and Z. But the col "ID" will contain the unique ID, DATE will contain the latest date for that ID and the rest of the cols will have the values corresponding to the latest time stamp (TS_EVENT) for that particular ID.

E.g., in this case for ID0026A the dataframe should look like

```
   ID       DATE       X   Y  Z
ID0026A  2013-03-27    0   0  0
ID0026A  2013-01-03  100 354 25
```

My dataframe contains 1.2million records and 6000 unique IDs

Note: str of ID is character, str of DATE is date, str of TS_EVENT is character and the rest numeric

So, first I want to convert TS_EVENT into a date-time object and then create the required dataframe.

How can I do this in R?

Comment: What if the latest date occurs more than once? That is, in your example, if there was another row with ID=ID0026A, DATE=2013-03-27, X,Y,Z=1, then do you want to output both rows with DATE=2013-03-27?

Comment: Your example (required result) doesn't comply with your question. ID is not unique and DATE is not the latest date for that ID (there are two different dates). As for the conversion of TS_EVENT to date-time object you can see how to do it in my (original) reply.

Answer (score 3):

Regarding the size of your data, I would use a `data.table` solution.

If your data is already sorted:

```
library(data.table)
DT <- as.data.table(dat)
DT[,tail(.SD,1),'ID']
# ID       DATE   X   Y  Z
# 1: ID0026A 2013-03-27 100 354 25
```

otherwise:

```
DT[,.SD[which.max(as.Date(DATE)),],'ID']
```

PS: dat is :

```
dat <- read.table(text=" ID       DATE       X   Y  Z
ID0026A  2013-01-03    25   0  0
ID0026A  2013-01-03     0   0  0
ID0026A  2013-01-03     0   0  0
ID0026A  2013-01-03     0   0  0
ID0026A  2013-01-03     0   0  0
ID0026A  2013-03-27   100 354 25",header=T)
```

---

In the development version of `data.table`, the argument `fromLast` is implemented for both `duplicated` and `unique` methods for data.table. You could therefore just do (assuming that the column is ordered by `ID, DATE`:

```
require(data.table) ## >= 1.9.3
unique(setDT(dat), by=c("ID"), fromLast=TRUE)
```

Answer (score 2):

Here are three approaches:

```
df <- read.table(header=T, text="ID       DATE       X   Y  Z
ID0026A  2013-01-03    25   0  0
ID0026A  2013-01-03     0   0  0
ID0026A  2013-01-03     0   0  0
ID0026A  2013-01-03     0   0  0
ID0026A  2013-01-03     0   0  0
ID0026A  2013-03-27   100 354 25
ID0026B  2013-12-03     0   1  1
ID0026B  2013-11-03     0   0  0", colClasses=c("factor", "Date", rep("integer", 3)))

aggregate(df[order(df$DATE), ], list(df$ID), tail, 1)[-1]

library(dplyr)
df %.% 
  arrange(DATE) %.% 
  group_by(ID) %.%  
  filter(DATE == tail(DATE, 1))

library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(df, key=c("DATE"))
dt[, last(.SD), by="ID"]
```

Comment: Note that `Date == tail(Date, 1)` will return all matches where as `last(.SD)` will only give the last row for each `ID`.

Answer (score 1):

You could do it easily with dplyr package like this:

```
x <- data.frame(ID=c(1,2,2), DATE=c("2012-01-03","2013-03-01","2013-03-02"), X=c(4,5,6))
df <- group_by(x,ID)
summarise(df, date=DATE[which.max(DATE)], X=X[which.max(DATE)])
```

If multiple latest dates are possible then you could do it like this

```
# df is the name of your dataframe
library(dplyr)
df %.% group_by(ID) %.% filter(DATE==DATE[which.max(DATE)])
```

edit:
conversion of TS_EVENT to date-time object can be done like this:

```
df$TS_EVENT <- as.POSIXct(df$TS_EVENT, format="%Y-%m-%d %I:%M:%S %p", tz="UTC")
```

Comment: I am getting the error
`Error: expecting a single value`
is it beacause I have cols X,Y and Z.
How will the code change if I have 3 cols?

Comment: Are latest dates unique or can we have more rows with the latest date?

Comment: Yes you are correct, so I should put it this way:
We will consider the last date for that ID.
Apologies for missing out on this point

Comment: You could use `df %.% group_by(ID) %.% filter(DATE==DATE[which.max(DATE)])`

Comment: could you please post the full code. I am a newbie in R

Comment: I've added it to the answer

Comment: `Error: incorrect length (0), expecting: 1`
I am replacing DATE with my original date variable name. Is it the correct thing to do?

Comment: Please see my edited question and provide a solution to my problem

Answer (score 1):

If the dates are arranged in ascending order, you can use:

```
dat[!duplicated(dat$ID, fromLast = TRUE), ]
```

Comment: @Arun Thanks for pointing out! I modified my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will help, but as you have 1.2 mln rows data.table would be better

```
library(plyr)
ddply(df,~ID,function(x){x[x$DATE==max(x$DATE),]})
```